# "too high" vs "so high"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

My brother in the middle school had a question in his vocab exam.

It says: The roof was .....  high that no one can touch it.

1. to
2. so
3. such
4. too

He thinks so high is correct, however, I am more into using too instead of so.
What would be the correct answer ?

Thanks

Comment: I think both are correct, `too` is more logically sound.

Comment: @Tiw thank you, you can answer and I will accept it if you wish.

Comment: Wait wait, others may have better ideas. Also my answer is too short to be a good answer :)

Comment: In that sentence, "too high" is absolutely wrong.  That makes no sense.  The answer is "so high."  The guy who said "too is more logically sound" must not be a native English speaker because that's not right at all.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman  Okay, you can add the answer as well and I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is ungrammatical:

> ✘ The roof was **too** high that no one can touch it.

It would be fine if the rest of the sentence were rephrased in one of a few ways:

> The roof was too high *for anyone to touch*.
>   The roof was too high, *and* no one *could* touch it.

But I'm assuming the question doesn't allow for the rest of the sentence to be modified in any way.

The only word you can drop into the sentence *as it is* that keeps it grammatical is *so*.

Comment: yeah it was a multiple choice question and it does not allow for the sentence to be modified as you mentioned.

Comment: but even *the roof was so high that no one can touch it* is weird because of the change of tense from *was* to *can* - for my money it should be *was... could* or *is... can*.

Comment: @Minty Yes, I agree with you.  As far as the verb tense goes, I would take it to be the *best of available bad choices*.

Comment: Could you please explain why `too` is ungrammatical in the sentence?

Comment: @Tiw Not at all easily, I'm afraid. It's one of those things that, as a native speaker, I just *know* is wrong. I can't think of a simple explanation for it.

Comment: @JasonBassford Fair enough, at least I know that it sounds not right to native speakers. Thanks.

Comment: @Tiw: **Too** is never matched with **that**, so you cannot construct a valid sentence containing "too high that"  The proper construction is "so...that."

Comment: @CanadianYankee  Is there any explicit grammar rule about it? Or just convention?

Comment: @Tiw - It's not a grammar rule per se; it's just a fact of vocabulary that **so...that** is a common construction for joining two related ideas with a cause-and-effect relationship - see [this exercise](https://www.englishgrammar.org/combining-sentences-sothat/) for example - and **too...that** isn't.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I think it's so understood idiomatically that it hasn't been explicitly spelled out.

Comment: @CanadianYankee  Thanks for the explaining and information :)

Comment: @CanadianYankee , thanks for sharing the exercise. I got the idea of constructing a sentence using so..that.